# Setting a navigation property in addition to select all in linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a linq query similar to the following that joins with the entity ProductCategories:

```
var list = from p in db.Products
           join pc in db.ProductCategories on p.ProductCategoryId equals pc.Id
           select new Product()
           {
              Id = p.Id, Name = p.Name, CategoryName = pc.Name
           };
```

Lets say I want to select p.* and in addition set the CategoryName navigation property from ProductCategories. Is this possibe? Or will I always have to specify everything when using navigation properties?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861059/select-all-columns-after-join-in-linq), it's not quite a duplicate but it's a variation.

Comment: So in my case would I just do select new { p.Id, p.Name, pc.Name } if I only needed those 3 properties and all of them were part of my Project object?

Comment: Spot on, yeah! As long as you don't need the `*` you're OK.

Comment: So lets say I do want to select all of product and in addition CategoryName what would I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an anonymous object and select your product object under one property and the category name under another property

```
select new 
       {
          Product = p, Name = p.Name, CategoryName = pc.Name
       };
```

[image]

Comment: This will automatically map to my Product entity as long as CategoryName is a property?

Comment: The CategoryName and  Product will  map as long as your join is correct

Answer (score 0):

The following should work as well if you want the entire thing, and your navigation properties are set up correctly (Make sure you have `using System.Data.Entity;` at the top of your file:

```
var list = db.Products.Include(p=>p.ProductCategories);
```

or a more simple anonymous class:

```
var list = db.Products.Select(p=>new { 
    p.Id,
    p.Description,
    ProductCategoryName=p.ProductCategories.Name});
```